# Basic Objective-C Import Issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, import, mopub

In my AppController I have an `if( _adView )` call. `if( _adView )` is declared in MoPubManager.h. So, I added in `#import "MoPubManager.h"` in the top on my AppController. But, I'm getting an error that highlights the `if( _adView )` call, and it states "Use of undeclared identifier." I though that importing the header would fix this. This is probably a really novice question, I'm still very new to Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `_adView` is a property of `"MoPubManager.h"`, then you can access the

```
_adView
```

in any other controller by importing `"MoPubManager.h"` in that controller and create an object of that `"MoPubManager.h"`

like `MoPubManager *obj = [MoPubManager alloc]init];`

then you can access `_adView` by using `obj._adview`

Note:You can set the `_adView` with properties `nonatomic` or `assign`.If it is set to `assign` property you can change the value of `_adView` from any other controller

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, that got rid of the errors! One more small thing, I'm calling `[self hideBanner:YES];`, it is in MoPubManager as well, but it is an actual method (I think that the name, sorry still really new at this), and I have a warning saying "-hidebanner not found".

Comment: declare the method "hidebanner" in MoPubManager.h.

Comment: It looks like I already have, in MoPubManager.h it says `- (void)hideBanner:(BOOL)shouldDestroy;`. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, is there an Accessor for _adView, as declared in moPubManager.h?

I mean do you see something like... ?

**(in moPubManager.h)** `@property (assign) id adView;`

Also, always remember that variables "belong to" classes. There is no such C-like thing as "_adView" in your AppController file, simply because you imported it's header. What WOULD work is something like :

`if ([moPub adView]) {...` in your AppController

provided that :

- Your AppController has defined a moPubManager instance (`moPubManager* moPub`)
- adView has its accessors in place :

In moPubManager.h :

```
@interface moPubManager : NSObject
{
id _adView;
...
}

@property (assign) id _adView;
```

In moPubManager.m :

```
@implementation moPubManager

@synthesize adView=_adView;

...
```

Comment: I think so, its just `@property (nonatomic, retain) MPAdView *adView;`, should I add in your code in moPubManager.h? Thanks.

Comment: Is there an instance of moPubManager in your AppController class? Like `moPubInstance* moPubManager`? If so, you could access it (from your AppController) by using `if ([moPubInstance adView]) { }`, etc, etc,... ;-)